# git merge produces wrong output file

Tags: git

I am trying to merge using commit ids as below.

```
git clone -b develop repo.git
git merge <commit id>
```

This merge command producing the output as

```
Auto-merging package.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in base.json
Auto-merging file.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file.txt
```

something like that. But when I look at the `package.json` file (which was auto-merged successfully), it has wrong content. Wrong content means some of lines are getting repeated even though source file does not have that content. I compared file in `develop` branch with file in `commit id`.

Why did git auto-merge produce wrong file?

Comment: Because it *hasn't* auto-merged. That message tells you it failed to do so, now you have to resolve the conflicts manually. Presumably you're seeing stuff like `>>>>>>>` which git uses to highlight the sections it was unable to deal with. See e.g. https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/

Comment: Why did you merge a specific commit? It's a valid but rare operation. And the merge encountered conflicts.

Comment: problem is with auto merge file package.json not with merge conflict files.

Comment: There is no way to tell without looking at the files. Presumably the two branched both introduced the same things, which when merged ended up as duplicates. You saying that the files doesn't have those changes doesn't help us, all we can say is "ok then, then it must be something else".

Answer (score 0):

In this step, you should resolve your conflicts. What IDE do you use? If you use Android Studio or InteliJ, you can go `VCS -> Git -> Resolve Conflicts...`